# Pass an object value in props to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Consider the code below, I need to pass an id which is in object format to another component by props. But I have try many time and it not working. I think I may have some thing mistake, but I'm not sure where is it.

Main page (updated):

```
render(props){
const data = this.state.data;
return (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <NavigationBar />
        <PurchaseInfoView show={this.state.displayModal} closeModal={this.closeModal} value={this.openModal}/>
          <div className="purchase-side">
            <div className="side-title">
              <h1>Purchase Order List</h1>
            </div>
            <hr class="solid" />
            {
              Object.keys(data).map((key) =>
                <div className="list-item">
                  <h2 onClick= {() => this.openModal(data[key].id)}> //get id
                    { data[key].item_name}
                  </h2>
                </div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="dads">        
        </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

openModal (Updated):

```
  openModal = (id) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        displayModal: true,
        id: id
      });
    console.log(id) // i can get the id from here id=1
  };
```

PurchaseInfoView to get the id (Updated).

```
class PurchaseInfoView extends Component {
 render() {
        console.log(this.props.id) // get undefined
        return (
        <div className="Modal"
            style={{
                transform: this.props.show ,
                opacity: this.props.show ? "1" : "0"
              }}
            >

            <h3>Purchase Order detail</h3>
            <p>Id: {this.props.id}</p> //cannot get it
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PurchaseInfoView;
```

console.log result:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.props.id` instead of `this.props.value.id` in the `PurchaseInfoView`?

Comment: You don't pass a id like a prop.Ofc will be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass an object to props here are the steps:

1. define the object in your parents state.
2. pass the object in props when calling components
3. get the object from props in child.

Here you are missing the second step!

You should try these:

**MainPage**

```
render(props){
const { data, modalObject, displayModal } = this.state; //use destructuring is more readable
return (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <NavigationBar />
        <PurchaseInfoView show={displayModal} closeModal={this.closeModal} modalObject={modalObject}/> //pass the object from destructuring state as props
        <div className="purchase-side">
          <div className="side-title">
            <h1>Purchase Order List</h1>
          </div>
          <hr class="solid" />
          {
            Object.keys(data).map((key) =>
              <div className="list-item">
                <h2 onClick= {() => this.openModal(data[key].id)}> //get id
                  { data[key].item_name}
                </h2>
              </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="dads">        
      </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

**OpenModal**

```
  openModal = (id) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        displayModal: true,
        modalObject: {id: id, ...any others key/val pair}
      });
  };
```

**PurchaseInfoView**

```
class PurchaseInfoView extends Component {
 render() {
        const { modalObject} = this.props; //here get your object from props
        console.log(modalObject.id);// here you have the object
        return (
        <div className="Modal"
            style={{
                transform: this.props.show ,
                opacity: this.props.show ? "1" : "0"
              }}
            >

            <h3>Purchase Order detail</h3>
            <p>Id: {modalObject.id}</p>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Tell me if you have any question in comment ;)

NB: i did this with an object (aka {} ) if you needed more things in your modal than just id. If just id is needed you just have to replace the modalObject by just the "id" you need

Cheers!

**EDIT**: for this solution to work you have to either:

- initialise your state to this at least:

  **this.state={ modalObject : { id: ''}}**
- or make a not null test in your child component before displaying the element like so:

  Id: {modalObject && modalObject.id ? modalObject.id : ' '}

These are needed because on first render your state will have the initial state you setted so if you didnt set anythin or didnt test for a value... well... it's undefined! :)

(note if id is null instead of having an undefined error you will have a blank space displaying in your modal)

Comment: Hi @Palencar. Thanks for your clearly explanation. But when I try to update my code with your correction, I get the error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".

Comment: Mayb is it related to objectModal ={modalObject}?

Comment: yeah sorry i misstyped here, i edited the code with modalObject everywhere ;) , i also added an Edit for the error you get, don't forget to initialise your state so you do not have undefined. Other solution is to make a not null test in the child component to see if the modal Object is defined *before* adding elements who needs it in render

Comment: Great, Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are calling it wrongly. It should be {this.props.id}

```
render() {
        console.log(this.props.id);
        return (
        <div className="Modal">
            <h3>Purchase Order detail</h3>
                <p>Id: {this.props.id}</p>  //Changed line
        </div>
        );
    }
```

Inside main page pass the id to PurchaseInfoView and access it as a prop

```
   <PurchaseInfoView show={this.state.displayModal} closeModal={this.closeModal} value={this.openModal} id={this.state.id}/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your guidance. But I still get undefined in the console.log

Comment: Hi @sv12, sure. I already updated the code. Have a look please

Comment: @kokoka Its not being sent to the PurchaseInfoView component

Comment: Oh, I got it. Should it be 
 <PurchaseInfoView show={this.state.displayModal} closeModal={this.closeModal} id={this.state.id}/>